# COPY doesn't copy symfony project into php container

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I try to dockerize a symfony project.

Docker compose at the root of the project:

```
version: "3"

services:
    php:
        build:
            context: ./docker/php
    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./docker/nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
```

At the end of /docker/php/Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /var/www/symfony
COPY . /var/www/symfony
```

I expect whole project to be copied into /var/www/symfony

But when I:

```
docker exec -it my-container /bin/bash
```

What I see is an empty folder.

Why can't docker copy all directory structure into symfony folder?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that Symfony is installed at the root of your project's directory. If that is the case, then your build context is wrong.

Docker will only make the files inside your build context available during the build, you can see it as the root directory of the build.

If your `context: ./docker/php` is there in order to use a different Dockerfile, then you should specify the Dockerfile's path and keep `.` as your build context.

```
version: "3"

services:
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    nginx:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

Let me know if that works